# Как создать текстовый файл на локальном компьютере Windows запустив Python скрипт на Linux?

Tags: python, linux, windows, файлы

Есть компьютер, который стоит на Contos 7, на нем нужно запустить файл с Python скриптом, который создаст текстовый файл на компьютере в локальной сети, который стоит на Windows, зная его ip адрес.

Пробовал запустить на Contos файл с кодом

```
with open("\\\\192.168.20.207\\PBXRecords\\test.txt", "a") as text_file:
    text_file.write("xyq")
```

Но текстовый файл не создается. Создается файл с названием "\\192.168.20.207\PBXRecords\test.txt" в папке со скриптом Python, при открывании которого создается пустой файл test.txt в папке 192.168.20.207\PBXRecords.

Как мне создать текстовый файл на локальном компьютере Windows запустив Python скрипт на Linux и сохранить при этом содержание файла?

Comment: На Windows должна быть настроена сетевая папка (shared folder). На linux эта папка должна быть смонтирована куда-то (поисковой запрос "centos how to mount smb shared directory"). Она будет доступна не по ip адресу, а как директория в файловой системе. После этого просто пишите файл внутрь этой смонтированной директории.

Comment: а как centos поймет, на каком компьютере находится сетевая папка, без ip адреса? Это де не виртуальная машина, которая установлена на windows, это совсем разные компьютеры

Comment: Вы при монтировании сетевой папки укажете этот адрес.